# How to modify a file php

Tags: file, design-patterns

I am trying to modify a text file I am using PHP or also I can use the C# the file that I am working on a text file consists of strings for example

> TM_len=      --------------------------------------------
>   EMM_len      --------------------------------------------
>   T_len=45      CTGCCTGAGCTCGTCCCCTGGATGTCCGGGTCTCCCCAGGCGG
>   NM_=2493      ----------------ATATAAAAAGATCTGTCTGGGGCCGAA

and I want to delete those four lines from the file if I found that one line consists of only "`-`" no characters in it and of course save to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? I wrote it in a easy to understand and "not-shortened" way:

```php
$newfiledata = "";
$signature = "    ";
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r"); // open file
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) { // read line by line
        $pos =  strpos($line, $signature); // locate spaces in line text
        if ($pos) {
            $lastpart = trim(substr($line, $pos)); // get second part of text
            $newstring = trim(str_replace('-', '', $line)); // remove all dashes

            if (len($newstring) > 0) $newfiledata .= $line."\r\n"; // if still there is characters, append it to our variable
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
// write new file
file_put_contents("newfile.txt", $newfiledata);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response but there nothing happened on the file please check the link of the file and another link of the desired output for the file.[download the file and required output file](http://www.filetourl.com/fec7213fe7)